# How to know if blender freezes, in larger render jobs command line

Tags: rendering, animation, command-line

I am rendering animations, and randomly i note that Blender freezes.
It happen not that often, but when i render at around 18:00 to note the next day it crashed on 18:15 instead of working whole night, then i lost quite some time.

I run Blender by command line with startup switches. The problem with freezes is that its not a hard crash (so i could detect that blender was gone from windows taskmanager, by coding). So the only indication i can think of is that the GPU fans all turn of for a longer while, but i don't know of ways to query in my GPU fans to check if their fans are on (i code in c#).

Comment: Update i found out how to know it has halted. I'll publish a script for it later